# Creating temporary HTML code

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I try to make my code more modular. Currently I include *jspf* file which contain code for [jQuery Dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) into any required *jsp* file.

I want to put this HTML code into JS file, so I only need to include one .js file instead of two:

```
function activateZoomingDialog() {
    var tmpId = ???;
    tmpId.innerHTML = '<input type="text"></input>...';
    $(tmpId).dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: 'Select area size',
        ...
    });
}
```

How to create and maintain (life-cycle) temporary DOM structure? jQuery solution will be acceptable.

Comment: `var tmpId = $("<div>");` then remove it when you destroy the dialog.

Comment: @KevinB Yea. I can remove by **tmpId.remove();** jQuery call! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function activateZoomingDialog() {
    var tmpId = '<div><input type="text"></input>...</div>';
    $(tmpId).dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: 'Select area size',
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: With that in mind (that it automatically appends it to the dom for you), i wonder if the destroy method will actually result in the div being automatically removed, since it wasn't part of the DOM to begin with. Edit: Nope, it doesn't. jQueryUI fails! - http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/HaxYj/

Comment: Indeed. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/HaxYj/ You're just too fast for me today `:)`

Comment: Thanks! By putting id into top level element or keeping reference to jQuery **$('...')** I can remove unused code... +1